# Dynamic decoration QGIS3

Tags: qgis-3

I try to make «copyright» decoration in QGIS dynamic.
I have a surface layer «COMMUNE» with a "NAME" field.
I try to write an expression that allows me to display this "NAME" in the decoration, I manage to get the center with `[%geom_to_wkt(  @map_extent_center) %]`

but then I get lost between the get_feature and attribute().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to display the Name of the Commune that is in the center of the map in your "copyright" decoration?

If yes, this expression should get the job done:

```
aggregate(
 layer:= 'COMMUNE',
 aggregate:='concatenate', 
 expression:="NAME", 
 filter:=contains( $geometry, @map_extent_center),
 concatenator:=', ')
```

Comment: That's work with this syntax : [% aggregate( 'communes','concatenate',"NAME",contains( $geometry, @map_extent_center),',  ')%]. thx